# Two divs getting stacked up on each other. How to avoid it?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am new to bootstrap and web development. I wanted to make a responsive div which always maintains a length to width ratio of 16:9. With a header and footer section above this responsive portion. But the header and footer sections are stacked up on each other. Any help would be appreciated.

html

```
<div class="post-card-outer">
                <div class="post-card-inner">
                    <div class="space-header">
                    </div>
                    <div class=" post-content">
                        <div class="col-sm-6 content-leftcol">
                            <div class="image-sec-post-card">
                                <img class = "image-post-card" src="3.jpeg">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 content-rightcol">
                            right
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="space-footer">
                        GGDYGDYGDYGDYGYDGDGYD
                    </div>
                </div><!--post-card-inner-->
            </div><!--post-card-outer-->
```

css

```
    .post-card-outer{
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9= 56.25 %; 4:3 = 75%*/
    position: relative;
    background: coral;
    margin-top:50px;
}
.post-card-inner{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.space-header {margin-top:-10px; height:10px; background-color:red;}
.space-footer {margin-bottom:-10px; height:10px; background-color:red;color:white;}
.post-content{
    min-height:100%; background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    top: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;
}
.content-leftcol{
    background-color:black;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}
.content-rightcol{
    background-color:blue;
    width:50%;
}
.image-sec-post-card{
    border:1px solid white;
  vertical-align: middle;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-post-card{
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if your header is meant to be at the very top and your footer is meant to be at the very bottom of the page/element then youR could use absolute or fixed positioning.

When you use absolute positioning the element is automatically set to the top-left of the window/element. You can think of it as a (0,0) positioning on a grid. Once you tell the element to be positioned absolutely you can use the TOP, RIGHT, BOTTOM, and LEFT properties. These properties directly influence the origin of your element. For example Top:0 will place your element at the very top of the window and Bottom:0 will place your element at the very bottom of the window. If you wanted to put a little space in between the element and the side of the window then you could simply increase the number. Top:20px or Top:2vh

Fixed positioning is nearly the same except your element will be static and wont move even if you try to scroll up or down. This is how you achieve fixed navigation bars and fixed footers.

```
.space-header {margin-top:-10px; height:10px; background-color:red;top:0;position:absolute;}

.space-footer {margin-bottom:-10px; height:10px; background-color:red;color:white;bottom:0;position:absolute;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
body{ margin:0; padding:0; color:#fff;} .space-header {height:50px; background-color:red;} .space-footer {height:50px; background-color:red;color:white;} .post-content{min-height:100%; background-color:green;} .content-leftcol{background-color:black;width:50%;height:47vw; float:left;} .content-rightcol{background-color:blue;width:50%;height:47vw;   float:left;} .image-sec-post-card{border:1px solid white;vertical-align: middle;overflow: hidden;}.image-post-card{max-width:100%; max-height:100%; border:1px solid green;} .clearfix{clear:both; float:none;}

<body><div class="space-header">Header
                </div>
                   <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class=" post-content">
                    <div class="col-sm-6 content-leftcol">
                        <div class="image-sec-post-card">
                            <img class = "image-post-card" src="3.jpeg">Left
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-6 content-rightcol">
                        right
                    </div>
                       <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <div class="space-footer">
                  Footer
                </div>
            </div> </body>
```